# NEO 6M data is not working properly with uno

Tags: arduino-uno, gps, tinygps

I am using a arduino uno and neo 6m gps module. The problem I am facing is quite weird. When I connected the setup the data from neo6M was seen in serial monitor, I even printed it on a Oled display. It was a close room at night. I used tiny gps plus plus library to parse the data. I got both latitude longitude. After disconnected the circuit i tried again and that is when nothing came out in serial monitor. The same sketch did not work for a day. But again at afternoon at some point i got the data properly. 
Sometimes the red led is blinking but nothing happens. 
While I change the rx and tx pins in software serial it got data but then again same problem and changing pins don't work. I have tested it in front of my window so there must be a good signal. 
Can someone tell me what is wrong with the system? I have so far waited long enough like 10 mins to get the data but nothing. I have to present the project by tomorrow in office.
This is the code : 
https://pastebin.com/TMRYXFNw

Comment: I am using this tutorial https://lastminuteengineers.com/neo6m-gps-arduino-tutorial/

Comment: Unless you can format your code properly (select it, then press the `{}` button in the editor) no one is going to look twice at your question.

Comment: Sorry for that. But in my phone i did not have a formatting option.